# No Gift Option "Pre selected" Need to fix this please

Tags: premiums

Hi so i have a premium contribution page set up and i noticed the "no gift" option is pre selected and grayed out so i cant change it. I need this option to be deselected until the user chooses it. The image below shows what im talking about and heres a link directly to the page

http://www.mendleton.com/merchandise/

[image: Grayed out radio buttons circled in red]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got some JavaScript errors.  That's going to break all your JavaScript, including the premium enable/disable script.  See if this post on [troubleshooting JavaScript for CiviCRM can help you](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850)?